# Handle Oracle TO_DATE(1, 'j') in JAVA

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, jpa

In our Oracle Database, there are Date columns that are filled with **TO_DATE(1, 'J')**, in other words **(00/00/0000)**. 
When mapping that table into Java, with @Entity and @Table annotations, that date column returns the value **-4712-01-01T00:00:00.000+0000**.

I'd like to know how should I handle that date in Java? If I need to return it to someone else, should I convert it to something else? Is there any good practice established for this case?

Answer (score 0):

All right - Julian date starts on 01-Jan-4712 BC.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day

If you want to receive January 1, 1 year from the birth of Christ, fill in Oracle table to_date(1721424, 'J').

Comment: Maybe you could provide a sample script ? Thanks

Comment: Alright, actually the database is correct, I need it like that. My desire is to handle that nicely in java. Is there a way I could convert that julian date with java 11, using LocalDateTime? It could just be convert from the first day of Julian Calendar to the first day of Gregorian calendar, it would already help.